# Send html table with Spring Boot Mail

Tags: java, spring

I want to create service that will send email messages to recipients. This message should be presented as a table which is filled from entity fields. I'm using Spring Boot Mail.

Solved this task with StringBuilder.

Simple MailSender configuration:

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
    mailSender.setPort(587);
    
    mailSender.setUsername("my.gmail@gmail.com");
    mailSender.setPassword("password");
    
    Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    
    return mailSender;
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
...
public class Mark {

    @Column(name = "account_login")
    private String accountLogin;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "account_view_id")
    private String accountViewId;

    @Column(name = "mark_text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "report_date")
    private LocalDate reportDate;
    //tostring, getters, setters, constructors
}
```

Method in one of the service to send email:

```
public void send(String subject, String htmlMsg, String sendTo)  {
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, false, "utf-8");
            message.setContent(htmlMsg, "text/html");
            helper.setTo(sendTo);
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            mailSender.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            log.error(e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Service which generates html table:

```
@Service
public class TableGenerationService {

    @Autowired
    private Mark markRepository;

    public String generateReportMessage(List<Mark> marks) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = generateCommonHtmlHead();

        for (Mark mark : marks) {

            stringBuilder.append("<tr>");
            stringBuilder.append("<td>").append(mark.getAccountLogin()).append("</td>");
            stringBuilder.append("<td>").append(mark.getText()).append("</td>");
            stringBuilder.append("<td>").append(mark.getId()).append("</td>");
            stringBuilder.append("<td>").append(message.getReportDate()).append("</td>");
            stringBuilder.append("</tr>");
        }
        generateCommonFooter(stringBuilder);
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }


    private StringBuilder generateCommonHtmlHead() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        return stringBuilder.append("<head>")
                .append("<h1>Status<h1>")
                .append("</head>")
                .append("<body>")
                .append("<table border=1>")
                .append("<tr>")
                .append("<th>Author id</th><th>Authour Name</th><th>Content</th><th>Date</th>")
                .append("</tr>");
    }

    private void generateCommonFooter(StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
        stringBuilder.append("</table></body>");
    }


    public String generateReportMessage() {
        List<Mark> all = markRepository.findAll();
        return generateReportMessage(all);
    }
}
```

I tested this and it works kinda good. But I think StringBuilder is not good idea for this task.
Are there other tools for generating html tables? Should i use thymeleaf/freemarker? What if i want to add css to table? This solution with StringBuilder will be hard to read. Or if no other tools are available, how can I improve the solution with StringBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally use Apache FreeMarker for such tasks, and here’s why you should use the template engine too:

- You already realized that it would be hard to read if you add additional content such as CSS styles;
- Your content presentation is coupled with the logic, you build it manually, looping through data etc. – FreeMarker (or another template engine) does that for you;
- It is way easier to update the [template](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template.html) and upgrade the [data model](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_datamodel.html) than to modify the code every time;
- You will need a basic [configuration](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config.html) and implementation for creating the content with templates and data models that you can reuse instead of duplicating or adding the code for building various specifics manually.

Here is a pretty good example to get started (has an example for tables too): https://www.dariawan.com/tutorials/spring/spring-boot-freemarker-crud-example/

Comment: Can I use FreeMarker without Controller layer?

Comment: Can you explain, how to send FreeMarker html file via email? Through File/Files methods? For example I've html file `main.ftlh` in templates folder.

Comment: FreeMarker will return a result in a form of processed template with provided data. You can either set it as e-mail body (which you already do in the `send` method) or attach the content as a file.

Comment: I think you should include an example how to use it in your answer as the link may not work in the future.

Comment: Found good article about FreeMarker and email: https://memorynotfound.com/spring-mail-sending-email-freemarker-html-template-example/

Comment: Yes, that example looks fine as well.